# Binary Search Tree Using Templates in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, template, binary-search

I have made this BST using templates

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node<T> *pLeft;
    Node<T> *pRight;
    T val;

    Node<T>(T val)
    {
        this->val = val;
        pLeft = pRight = nullptr;
    }

    // Node<T>(const Node<T>& src); -> to be implemented
    // Node& operator=(const Node&); -> to be implemented
};


#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
class Tree
{
    Node<T>* root;
    Node<T>* insert_at_sub(T i, Node<T>*);
    Node<T>* delete_at_sub(T i, Node<T>*);
    int countNodes(Node<T> *p);
    void print_sub(Node<T> *p);
    Node<T>* minValue(Node<T>*);
    Node<T>* maxValue(Node<T>*);
    Node<T>* get_last(Node<T>*);
    Node<T>* get_first(Node<T>*);
    int t_size = 0;

public:
    Tree ()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        delete root;
    }

    void add(T i)
    {
        ++t_size;

        root = insert_at_sub(i, root);
    }
    void print()
    {
        print_sub(root);
    };

    bool contain(T i)
    {
        return contain_sub(i, root);
    }
    bool contain_sub(T i, Node<T> *p);

    void destroy(T i)
    {
        if(contain(i))
            root = delete_at_sub(i, root);
        else
            return;
    }

    void showFirst();
    void showLast();

    int get_size()
    {
        return t_size;
    }

    int getNumberLeftNodes()
    {
        return countNodes(root->pLeft);
    }

    int getNumberRightNodes()
    {
        return countNodes(root->pRight);
    }
};

template<typename T>
int  Tree<T>::countNodes(Node<T> *p)
{
    static int nodes;

    if(!p)
        return 0;
    if (p->pLeft)
    {
        ++nodes;
        countNodes(p->pLeft);
    }
    if (p->pRight)
    {
        ++nodes;
        countNodes(p->pRight);
    }

    return nodes + 1;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* Tree<T>::insert_at_sub(T i, Node<T> *p)
{
    if( ! p )
        return new Node<T>(i);
    else if (i <= p->val)
        p->pLeft = insert_at_sub(i, p->pLeft);
    else if (i > p->val)
        p->pRight = insert_at_sub(i, p->pRight);

    return p;
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::print_sub(Node<T> *p)
{
    if(p)
    {
        print_sub(p->pLeft);
        std::cout << p->val << std::endl;
        print_sub(p->pRight);
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool Tree<T>::contain_sub(T i, Node<T> *p)
{
    if (!p)
        return false;
    else if(i == p->val)
        return true;
    else if (i <= p->val)
        contain_sub(i, p->pLeft);
    else
        contain_sub(i, p->pRight);
}

template<typename T>

Node<T> *Tree<T>::minValue(Node<T> *p)
{
    Node<T> *current = p;

    while(current && current->pLeft)
        current = current->pLeft;

    return current;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T> *Tree<T>::maxValue(Node<T> *p)
{
    Node<T> *current = p;

    while(current && current->pRight)
        current = current->pRight;

    return current;
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::showLast()
{
    Node<T> *last = maxValue(root);

    if(last)
        std::cout << last->val;
    else
        std::cout << "";
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::showFirst()
{
    Node<T> *first = minValue(root);

    if(first)
        std::cout << first->val;
    else
        std::cout << "";
}


template<typename T>
Node<T>* Tree<T>::delete_at_sub(T i, Node<T>* p)
{
    if (i < p->val)
        p->pLeft = delete_at_sub(i, p->pLeft);
    else if (i > p->val)
        p->pRight = delete_at_sub(i, p->pRight);
    else if(i == p->val)
    {
        if ( ! p->pLeft)
        {
            Node<T> *temp = p->pRight;
            delete p;

            return temp;
        }
        else if ( ! p->pRight)
        {
            Node<T> *temp = p->pLeft;
            delete p;

            return temp;
        }

        Node<T> *temp = minValue(p->pRight);

        p->val = temp->val;

        p->pRight = delete_at_sub(p->val, p->pRight);
    }

    return p;
}

#endif // TREE_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Tree.h"

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    string name;
public:
    Test () {}
    Test(string name_) : name(name_) {}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Test& t)
    {
        os << t.name;

        return os;
    }

    bool operator<(Test t);
    bool operator<=(Test t);
    bool operator>(Test t);
};

bool Test::operator<(Test t)
{
    return (name < t.name);
}

bool Test::operator<=(Test t)
{
    return (name <= t.name);
}

bool Test::operator>(Test t)
{
    return (name > t.name);
}

int main()
{
    Tree<int> tr;

/*
                       4
                    /      \
                   1        6
                 /  \      /  \
                0    2     5   9
                                 \
                                 89
                                /  \
                               12   222
                                 \
                                 32
                                /
                               22
*/

    tr.add(4);
    tr.add(6);
    tr.add(1);
    tr.add(9);
    tr.add(2);
    tr.add(0);
    tr.add(89);
    tr.add(12);
    tr.add(32);
    tr.add(5);
    tr.add(22);
    tr.add(222);


    //  tr.test();

   tr.showFirst();
   cout << endl;
   tr.showLast();
   cout << endl;

    Tree<string> bst;

    bst.add("Zanildo");
    bst.add("Helder");
    bst.add("Wilson");
    bst.add("Ady");
    bst.add("Adilson");
    bst.add("Patrick");


    bst.showFirst();
    cout << endl;
    bst.showLast();
    cout << endl;

    Tree<Test> test;

    test.add({"Jhonny"});
    test.add({"Bruno"});
    test.add({"Garry"});
    test.add({"Henry"});
    test.add({"Amber"});
    test.add({"Brandy"});
    test.add({"Danny"});
    test.add({"Cameron"});
    test.add({"Edla"});
    test.add({"Zenalda"});

    test.showFirst();
    cout << endl;
    test.showLast();
    cout << endl;

    //test.print();


    return 0;
}
```

I put all the `Tree` class functions implementation inside the header file because didn't want to put'em in a cpp file and having to add the explicit instantiation at the end of the file like this for example:

```
template class Tree<int>; // explicit instantiation
```

I also know I have to provide a `copy constructor` and an `assignment operator` for the `Node` class but I am still studying how to implement them correctly as this is my first time having the need to provide either of them. I have studied them before but while googling around came across the `copy-swap idiom` which is said to be the best approach so I have a few tabs open to study it and try to implement it. If anyone wish to give me a head start would be more than welcome.

An iterative BST is better for performance when the tree gets quite large but I have made the main functions for this BST `recursively` on purpose. I know how to implement those functions `iteratively` but not all of them yet.
After I want to create this BST entirely `iterative`.

Besides all this, what can be said about my BST with `template`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Make it explicit that it is a *binary* tree

Your class name is `Tree`, but there are many different types of trees. Make it clear that this is a binary tree, and name it `BinaryTree`.

## Move `class Node` inside `class Tree`

Move the declaration of `class Node` inside that of `class Tree`, in the `public` section. This makes it clear that this `Node` is specific to the tree you are implementing, and avoids a potention conflict with other classes that might have nodes.

Consider for example that you might also have an implementation of a linked list, which also consists of nodes named `Node`. If you would want to use both your binary tree and your linked list in the same program, you would get a conflict.

## Try to make your `Tree` look like other `STL` container classes

Have a look at what member functions STL containers define. The closest `STL` container to your binary tree is [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). You don't have to add all the functionality of an STL container right away, just first consider renaming some of your member functions to match that of the STL. For example, instead of `add()` and `destroy()`, use `insert()` and `erase()`. Instead of `get_size()`, use `size()`.

There are several benefits to this. First, for someone who is already familiar with other STL containers, it makes working with your `Tree` more intuitive. But that's not all: if you make it look enough like an STL container, then some of the [STL algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) might actually start to work on your `Tree` as well!

## Move printing out of `class Tree`

Instead of having a `print_sub()` function that only prints to `std::cout`, consider writing instead a function that walks the tree and takes a function as one of its argument, so that it allows the caller to decide what to do with each visited node. For example:

```
template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::visit_subtree(const Node<T> *p, std::function<void(const T&)> func)
{
    if (p)
    {
        visit_subtree(p->pLeft, func);
        func(p->val);
        visit_subtree(p->pRight, func);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::visit(std::function<void(const T&)> func)
{
    return visit_subtree(root, func);
}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
Tree<Test> test;
...
test.visit([](Test &val){std::cout << val << '\n';});
```

The advantage is that you can call it with any other function you like, so if you wanted to print it to `std::cerr` instead, or if you wanted to do something completely different with each element of the tree, you don't have to change your `Tree`'s `visit()` function.

However, another approach is:

## Implement iterators for your `Tree`

Try to implement an iterator class for your `Tree`, and provide `begin()` and `end()` member functions that return the appropriate iterators, to allow someone to loop over all the elements of the tree with a simple `for`-statement, like:

```
Tree<Test> test;
...
for (const auto &val: test)
    std::cout << val << '\n';
```

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls) for some good references on how to implement an iterator yourself. It is a bit of work, but it makes using your class much easier. Once you have it, you also get many things for free. For example, instead of having to write your own `minValue()` function, once you have iterators you can just use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) on an instance of a `Tree` class to get the smallest element.

## Fix the memory leak in the destructor

Your destructor only deletes the `root` node, not any of its children.

## Use `const` where appropriate

You should make arguments, variables, return values and whole member functions `const` whereever appropriate. For example, `countNodes()` does not modify the `Node<T>` that you give a pointer to as an argument, and it also doesn't change anything in `class Tree` itself. Therefore, you should declare it as:

```
int countNodes(const Node<T> *p) const;
```

The same goes for many other functions. Apart from catching potential errors and helping the compiler produce better optimized code, doing this will also allow these member functions to be called on `const` instances of `class Tree`.

Comment: **Move class Node inside class Tree** -> How `Node` inside the class `Tree` avoids a potential conflict with other classes that might have nodes?

Comment: **Move printing out of class Tree** Unfortunately I can't seem to understand this, how exactly does it work?

Comment: **"_if you make it look enough like an STL container, then some of the STL algorithms might actually start to work on your Tree as well!_"** -> Could you please clarify this statement?

Answer (score 3):

- There's no way to access the tree's nodes, so `contain_sub` is useless to clients.
- Even if it works, `contain_sub` doesn't return anything in two of its branches and looks gnarly.
- Use smart pointers or have a good reason not to.
- Don't copy items unless you're copying the tree itself; you're doing this a lot.
- Regarding iterators: remember that there are multiple ways to traverse a binary tree (pre/post/in/level order, and reverse).
- use_consistentNamingConventions (`getNumberLeftNodes` vs `get_size`).
- When would `getNumberLeftNodes` ever be useful to a client?
- Test your interface if you're going to write test code. 100% coverage is completely reasonable for a data structure.
- `insert_at_sub` could reduce to else returning the new node instead of having two returns
- "destroy" is semantically inaccurate for C++, it should be something like "erase".
- `destroy` is pretty inefficient and needs revising. Don't repeatedly traverse trees if you don't have to.

---

At a high level, why is this binary tree useful? Why not sort a vector or a list? Does this require fewer comparisons? Fewer pointer indirections? Fewer bytes allocated? It looks very slow at a cursory glance. If it's more optimal in some way than another data structure, write a test to demonstrate that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your review.I have a question, how would I write test code. What is that?

Comment: _**At a high level, why is this binary tree useful? Why not sort a vector or a list? _** Didn't understand the question

Comment: **When would getNumberLeftNodes ever be useful to a client?** -> It was just an exercise

Comment: **Don't copy items unless you're copying the tree itself, you're doing this a lot** - > Could you please point to an example in the code and provide a fix?

Comment: `contain_sub` is not meant for client and it is not supposed to return anything. It is just a helper function that takes the `root` node as a parameter.

Comment: Consider `void add(T i)` 
If T is a std::string, it's going to do a string copy every time insert_at_sub is called. So say you had a tree 1000 levels deep and a string 1000 characters long -- that will copy 1million bytes. Using std::move you could reduce this to 0 string copies. 

Consider making a test object that prints out in its copy constructor and copy assignment operator to test how often copies are happening. Or, make a non-copyable object and get it to compile.

Comment: If contain_sub is not meant for client, it should be private.

Your container should have some directive. For example, a binary tree should do O(logn) insertion. A vector does O(n) insertion. They both have O(logn) search times. So maybe its directive would be "build a searchable database faster than inserting into a vector". You can use this to help guide your designs. Otherwise maybe performance doesn't matter at all. In that case, there's no reason to optimize the amount of object copies the tree does.

Comment: regarding printing, imagine you took all the print functions out of the tree. How would you proceed to print out the tree using the remaining interface?

Comment: `contain_sub` is misplaced, hadn't noticed that.

Comment: So I would use `std::move` in `void add(T i)` like this: `root = std::move(insert_at_sub(i, root));`??

Comment: No, that is incorrect. It is difficult to teach the concept of r-value references in the comments section. Try to get your code to work with a non-copyable object type as T to help understand why this is important.

Answer (score 3):

A few extra points to the current answers:

- Tree will create a default copy constructor which will not behave as expected.
  As root is a raw pointer it will just do a shallow copy, assuming T is copiable (i.e. create a new pointer to the same data.)
  This will create unexpected behaviour if you copy the Tree and then modify one of the copies.
  As they both point to the same data both will be modified.
  You should either disable copying of Tree and Node, e.g. `Tree(const Tree&) = delete;`
  or write a custom copy that does a full deep copy of the data. The deep copy for Node would look something like this:

```
Node<T>(const Node<T>& src)
: val(src.val)
 {
    if(src.pLeft)
    {
        pLeft=*src.pLeft;
    }
    if(src.pRight)
    {
        pLeft=*src.pRight;
    }
 }
```

and something similar for Tree. NB I haven't done the copy-assignment here, you can either do something very similar to the copy constructor or implement a swap function and use that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom.

- I would strongly recommend using smart pointers. This would prevent the memory leak in Node,
  and would implicitly prevent copying if you use `unique_ptr`.
- Your Tree allows duplicate elements, I'm not sure if this is intentional, but it has some
  not entirely obvious behaviour. `add` will perfectly happily add multiple of the same data,
  and `destroy` will only remove the first matching element. If this is intentional it should probably
  be documented. In most cases it is probably not necessary for a search tree to have duplicate elements.
- Consider adding ways to add/remove multiple elements at once. This is probably quite a common 
  thing to do. The standard way would be a templated function taking a start and end iterator,
  that you can loop though.
- The performance of the tree is dependant on the order elements are added. This is not necessarily
  a problem, but is something to be aware of. If your tree is very unbalanced (e.g. the left nodes go a lot deeper than the right)
  some nodes will have to do many more checks to find than others. If you are interested in this
  you might want to look at self-balancing trees such as a red-black tree.

Comment: Having duplicates in the Tree was intentional, didn't know that it was not necessary to for a search tree to have duplicate elements. For the `destroy` though, that behavior was unintentional. while implementing/trying to implement the fixes mentioned in reviews above I tested the class more rigorously I saw that it has many problems, e.g. if you call the `get_size` function twice  the size in the second call will return  almost 2x bigger without adding any element to the tree in between the two functions calls.

Comment: Using `std::unique_ptr` in the `Node` function would be like this: `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> pRight; std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> pLeft`? I did so but it gave errors in the `Tree` class functions.

Comment: Yes, you will need to refactor at least delete_at_sub as it copies Node* which you cannot do with unique_ptr.

Comment: Refactoring always breaks stuffs along the way and as no with no surprise it broke a lot of stuff and it takes too much time to fix them as I have never worked with smart pointer, I will instead study smart pointers again (this time knowing I will be working with them immediately) and rebuild the BST. Thanks for review.